# Authenticate MyBB with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, forum, mybb

I am trying to make Laravel 5 work along MyBB.
This is what I currently have:

- Laravel 5 running
- MyBB running in /public/forum/

This means MyBB didn't load any Laravel classes.

How can I let Laravel 5 use the login session from MyBB? So that way you don't have to login on both systems.

Thanks,

Melvin

Comment: You can't let Laravel use the exact same session from MyBB, because Laravel doesn't use the default PHP way of handling sessions, instead it has its own implementation. You can get the session information from MyBB and use it in a Laravel session, but you'll still have two sessions. There is [this tutoria](http://community.mybb.com/thread-60422.html) l that shows how to integrate the MyBB login system into another website, but I don't know if that is what you really want or if it even plays nice with Laravel.